# Can't seem to apt-get update on kali linux [tried many ways

Tags: linux-kernel, apt-get

I keep getting such errors: None of these work for me guys, I've tried to change the sources in the sources.list files by enabling one, disabling the other and still no avail, I even tried to connect to the internet using wired instead of wifi. My terminal spits out an error as such:

```
root@kali:~# apt-get update
Get:1 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Get:2 http://103.1.138.146/ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages [16.3 MB]
Err:2 http://103.1.138.146/ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (16219097 != 16303971). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 103.1.138.146 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:16303971 [weak]
   - SHA256:bfa154b8fd021b85e9992a7a34ea14543edce6136589d8c7e276d46bf967a294
   - SHA1:e91a121dc124b0bafe6acfc01a0e2aad5fe565d4 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:4bd6e27fe0196c2d53a55bdcd1cf8e06 [weak]
  Release file created at: Sat, 18 Aug 2018 12:04:29 +0000
Reading package lists... Done                        
E: Failed to fetch http://103.1.138.146/ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  File has unexpected size (16219097 != 16303971). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 103.1.138.146 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:16303971 [weak]
    - SHA256:bfa154b8fd021b85e9992a7a34ea14543edce6136589d8c7e276d46bf967a294
    - SHA1:e91a121dc124b0bafe6acfc01a0e2aad5fe565d4 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:4bd6e27fe0196c2d53a55bdcd1cf8e06 [weak]
   Release file created at: Sat, 18 Aug 2018 12:04:29 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://103.1.138.146/ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali/dists/kali-rolling/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  
E: Failed to fetch http://103.1.138.146/ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali/dists/kali-rolling/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Maybe your source.list is your problem: Try this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373362/apt-get-not-working-on-my-kali-linux

Comment: Hmmm, thanks so much for your response, but even after following the instructions in the link, it still gave the same errors:( @R73

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple things that causes that problem:
1.) your PC or Laptop i not connected to your router or can't access it (try to ping google.co)
2.) your source list is empty (can i see your source list)

edit:

this are my last solution

1.) Theres a Problem just like you in this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429729/apt-get-update-error-in-kali-linux-after-dist-upgrade

2.) here's what i found on youtube: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxdky8gtocc

if this will not work then i don't have further solution to give you sorry

Comment: `root@kali:~# ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.68.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sc-in-f100.1e100.net (74.125.68.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=6.67 ms
64 bytes from sc-in-f100.1e100.net (74.125.68.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=10.6 ms
64 bytes from sc-in-f100.1e100.net (74.125.68.100): icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=8.60 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.673/8.626/10.604/1.608 ms
root@kali:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free`

Answer (score 0):

- first go to File Systems
- open etc folder
- open apt folder
- double click on sources.list
- go https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/
- there are two links and copy both two links and paste it on sources.list file
- save file
- type sudo apt-get update in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

According to the [Official Kali Linux Documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/) concerning the sources.list file. Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` should look exactly like this:

```
 deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
 # For source package access, uncomment the following line
 # deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Make sure there is no other repositories or lines because according to the documentation:

- The single most common causes of a broken Kali Linux installation are
  following unofficial advice, and particularly arbitrarily populating
  the system’s sources.list file with unofficial repositories. The
  following post aims to clarify what repositories should exist in
  sources.list, and when they should be used. Any additional
  repositories added to the Kali sources.list file will most likely
  BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL.

The single most common causes of a broken Kali Linux installation are following unofficial advice, and particularly arbitrarily populating the system’s sources.list file with unofficial repositories. The following post aims to clarify what repositories should exist in sources.list, and when they should be used.

Any additional repositories added to the Kali sources.list file will most likely BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL.

### If You Continue to Have Issues

Do you continue to get the initial error that you reported?

- Verify Network Connectivity `ping 8.8.8.8`

if it not work try this command to activate network connectivity

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```